# Set -webkit-tap-highlight-color of Android WebView in Java

Tags: java, android, css, xml, android-webview

I know I can do this in CSS (`-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)`), but how can I do it in Java for an Android WebView?

Thanks!